# InDesign CS4+ Data Merge with Remote Images?

Tags: remote, merge, adobe-indesign

Is it possible to use InDesign's data merge to link to remotely hosted images if the full path is known?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. The InDesign Scripting API has a Socket object, which provides low-level access to network functionality. You could then use something like the HTTP functionality in [Extendables](http://extendables.org/) library.